# Inline assembly with argument reorders code

Tags: c, assembly, arm, inline

I have a question about ARM inline assembly code. I am trying to call a function from a naked function, as shown below. It unexpectedly reorders the code.

```
extern void func_b();
__attribute__((naked)) static void func_a(void)
{
    asm volatile ( "push    {r0-r7, lr}" );
    asm volatile ( "bl      %0" : : "r"(func_b) );
    asm volatile ( "pop     {r0-r7, lr}\n"
                   "subs    pc, lr, #4" );
}
```

I got the following assembly code:

```
305c:   f642 20c7   movw    r0, #10951  ; 0x2ac7
3060:   b5ff        push    {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
3062:   f2c0 0000   movt    r0, #0
3066:   4780        bl      r0
3068:   e8bd 40ff   ldmia.w sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
306c:   f3de 8f04   subs    pc, lr, #4
```

My desired code should be:

```
305c:   b5ff        push    {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
305e:   f642 20c7   movw    r0, #10951  ; 0x2ac7
3062:   f2c0 0000   movt    r0, #0
3066:   4780        bl      r0
3068:   e8bd 40ff   ldmia.w sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
306c:   f3de 8f04   subs    pc, lr, #4
```

I have tried the asm volatile ( "" ::: "memory" ); compiler barrier but it does not work.

Comment: The reordering itself shouldn't be unexpected - ["Do not expect a sequence of asm statements to remain perfectly consecutive after compilation. If certain instructions need to remain consecutive in the output, put them in a single multi-instruction asm statement."](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm)

Comment: @Notlikethat Thank you for the pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the `"r"` constraint on the `funcb` address, you instruct the assembler to do a "jump with link" based on a register value. There is no such instruction in the ARM instruction set, however.

If you relax the `"r"` constraint to `"g"`, the code will probably be closer to what you desire.

Comment: Thank you so much, @mfro! It works with "g" constraint. I think I should look more into it.

Comment: The OP's question includes what looks like disassembly output for `bl r0`.  How else would ARM call through a function pointer?  (I mostly only know x86, so maybe you're right and there's a different instruction for that.)  Anyway, using extended asm at all is apparently unsupported in naked functions.  (see my answer).

Comment: @Peter With `blx r0` (or `mov lr, pc; mov pc, r0` if you feel silly) - the only valid operand for `bl` is a label.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: there is no such instruction like `bl <register>`.  If you assemble that code given above, you'll probably get complaints about an undefined label `r0`. A branch with register value would be `bx <register>` (and needs a lot more overhead).

Comment: Then what's the correct disassembly for the OP's `47 80` instruction?  Is that actually `blx r0`?  Sorry I don't have an ARM toolchain installed locally to check myself.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: yes, blx r0

Answer (score 1):

What you're calling "re-ordering" is not actually re-ordering of the `asm volatile` code.  All the asm code appears in source order.  What's happening is that the compiler interleaves some compiler-generated instructions between them.  This is what @Notlikethat pointed out.  This is expected for operand setup.

---

The [gcc manual points out that this usage of `naked` is unsupported](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html):

> Only basic asm statements can safely be included in
>   `__attribute__((naked))`  functions (see Basic Asm). While using
>   extended asm or a mixture of basic asm and C code may appear to work,
>   they cannot be depended upon to work reliably and are not supported.

[Basic Asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html) means `asm` statements without operands, so `asm volatile ( "bl   %0" : : "r"(func_b) );` is the problem.

As @artless_noise pointed out in a deleted answer, you don't need or want a function pointer in a register.  You should just use `asm("bl func_b");`.

Using a `"g"` constraint (as mfro's answer suggests) will let the compiler choose a memory operand, so you end up with `bl func_b`.  This is still technically unsupported, and pointless anyway, so don't do it.

---

If you want to write a `naked` function that takes args, look up in the ABI what registers to find them in.  Don't use inline-asm operands to get function args or access globals.